# Error in HTML code inside a php variable

Tags: php

I have this variable which contains HTML code and other variables. I am doing something wrong with the syntax but i don't know what. Help is appreciated.

```
$message = "
        <html>
        <head>
        <title> Statistics</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <p> The start was: " .$day."
        <p> The end was:  " .$day."
        </body>
        </html>
        ";
```

Comment: What is wrong with this? What do you expect to get and what do you actually have as result?

Comment: @Lucarnosky it just stops running when it comes to this line. I just want to echo the content of the $day variable.

Comment: It's working fine. Have you defined `$day`somewhere?

Comment: @TMA Try to comment away this portion of code and check if everything work fine, sometime the problem is near the line they give you the warning. BTW add </p> and close paragraph tag

Comment: did u try closing the </p> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Fabian Gr pointed out; You didn't close the `<p>` Tags... but then; not closing the `<p>` Tags is not enough to halt the Execution of PHP Script like you mentioned in the Comments. That Part is purely HTML-based and should not affect PHP by any means... In the worst case, your wrong Semantics could simply swallow the Markup but not throw any PHP Warning or Error....
Perhaps you could just save yourself the hassles and use PHP's `heredoc` like so:

```
    <?php
        $message =<<<MSG
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Statistics</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>The start was: {$day}</p>
                <p>The end was: {$day}</p>
            </body>
        </html>
      MSG;
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission : "A p element's end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, main, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul, element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element."

Answer (score 0):

You just need to close the

Tag.

so the solution of your problem Should be:

```
$message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Statistics</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p> The start was: " .$day."</p>
    <p> The end was:  " .$day."</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";
```

Comment: Great Observation!!! Though missing the Closing `</p>` Tags is not enough to halt the Script's execution. +10

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission : "A p element's end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, main, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul, element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element."